# bootstrap 3 template change mvc5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am learning mvc/asp.net in visual studio 2013 and want to try my hands on a first web application. Only thing is I don't like the default jumbotron template/theme that it comes with. I went to getbootstrap.org and I like the carousel or flatly templates/themes.

I have been scouring the net for any tutorial or resource to help me change the default theme in vs2013 with no success. So I wanted to know if anyone can help me get to the bottom of this. Just a how to swap templates/themes out from vs20xx so that I can create different templates/themes as I please.

Comment: I think you may want to start by checking out your _Layout.cshtml, and go from there.

Comment: MVC doesn't use *themes*. You control the layout, beginning to end.

Comment: Ok first thanks u guys for d help. I tried my hands on making a layout from d carousel option on bootstraps site and it worked ok but it doesn't really look right....

Comment: @Brendan can I accept your comment as an answer cos I have had to look at the template and I think my problem is solved.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are many sites will provide you free Bootstrap templates, as http://bootswatch.com/, checkout e.g. amelia; download  and rename theme  and copy theme `Amelia.css` [you can name it as you want] in to your Content folder, in `APP_Start.BundleConfig.cs` 
Update `RegisterBundles()` method as:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
"~/Content/bootstrap.css", "~/Content/Amelia.css"));
```

Remember to have your theme name last e.g. `Amelia.css` in `bundle.add`.
Folder Run project and you will see rendered theme.